# Vite React App deploy to Azure App Services fails

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-web-app-service, devops

I'm trying to deploy my Vite react app to azure as an app service, but after deploy I always get the default screen (see picture). I tried deploying manually from VS code, but also creating the following yaml file in GitHub actions.  The pipeline ran successfully and I still got this problem. I have my react-app in ./LOL_Contest/frontend, that's why I use that in the pipeline. What is the solution?

[image: Your web app is running and waiting for your content...]

```
name: Build and deploy Node.js app to Azure Web App - lolcontest-fe

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:        
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Node.js version
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: '18.x'

      - name: npm install, build, and test
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build --if-present
          npm run test --if-present
        working-directory: ./LOL_Contest/frontend

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: node-app
          path: .

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: node-app

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: 'lolcontest-fe'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{ ... }}
          package: ./LOL_Contest/frontend
```

I can not share the repository, but I have the following folder structure:

```
- DataAccess
- LOL_Contest
  -- frontend
```

I want to deploy the contents of the folder "frontend"

Comment: Could you please share your `GitHub Repository`?

Comment: I cant' share the repo, but I added my folder structure to the initial post

Comment: Are you following any Document. If yes, please share it once.

Comment: What do you mean by following any document? I'm not following tutorials, the .yml file was created by Azure Portal, I only added the working-directory, and updated the package in the last line

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old post, so you probably found the solution, but maybe it will help someone else.
I think what you have missing is the folder where vite is building the output app - the default is: *dist*
so, under the build section you need to add the folder name:

```
- name: Upload artifact for deployment job
    uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
    with:
      name: node-app
      path: dist
```

Also, depending on what app service plan you are using e.g. Windows or Linux you may need to add the start up command in your Azure portal.
If using Linux for your app service go to: Your web app > Configuration > Startup Command >

```
pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot --no-daemon
```

or, for SPA:

```
pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot --no-daemon --spa
```